# unityでインベントリシステムを作成する方法について

Tags: c#, unity3d

拾ったものをリストに入れる所までできましたが、どうやったらマイクラのようなインベントリシステムができますか？
何するべきなのかも分かりません

Comment: 海外の動画とかも見ましたが、スクリプトの内容が理解できませんでした

Comment: 問題点が漠然としすぎています。もっと問題を具体的にしたほうが的確な回答を得られると思います。

Answer (score 0):

インベントリシステムは大きなシステムです。全てのシステムは小さい機能の組み合わせて実装されているので、機能単位で１つずつ地道に理解と実装を繰り替えして学習していくことをおすすめします。

実装を優先するのであれば、インベントリシステムのアセットもあるようですのでそちらを探されるのが良いかと思います。

Comment: 問題点が漠然としすぎています。もっと問題を具体的にしたほうが的確な回答を得られると思います。　　＞＞　　リストに入っているアイテムをインベントリの枠の中に表示させる方法が分からないですね